# How to apply group by in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can the same logic be applied in sql stored procedure itself to get the same result as done in the following link post instead of using LINQ?

[Linq query having group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455003/linq-query-having-group-by)

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[WF_SPScanningReport_S]    
(    
        @COMPANYID VARCHAR(20),    
        @FROMDATE DATETIME,    
        @TODATE  DATETIME,
        @FromRecord int,         
        @ToRecord int,       
        @SortString varchar(200)   
)    
AS    
BEGIN    
declare @Query nvarchar(Max)     
    if(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortString)),'') <> '') 
        set @SortString='order by '+@SortString
    else 
        set @SortString='order by IMAGEID'



 SET NOCOUNT ON   
   set @Query=' CREATE TABLE #TABLE     
                (IMAGEID INT ,     
                SCANDATE DATETIME,    
                COUNT INT    
                )    

                INSERT INTO #TABLE(IMAGEID , SCANDATE)    
 SELECT IMAGEID , CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SCAN_DATE,101) AS DATETIME) SCANDATE FROM WF_IMAGES     
 WHERE COMPANYID='''+@COMPANYID+''' AND SCAN_DATE BETWEEN '''+cast(@FromDate as varchar)+''' AND '''+cast(@ToDate as varchar)+''' AND IMAGE_NAME <> ''BLANK.PDF'' AND ISNULL(''Reviewed'','''') <> ''X''



  UPDATE #TABLE    
     SET COUNT = S.COUNT1    
     FROM #TABLE T, (SELECT COUNT(SCANDATE) AS COUNT1 ,SCANDATE FROM #TABLE GROUP BY SCANDATE) S    
     WHERE T.SCANDATE= S.SCANDATE    



SELECT * FROM   (SELECT Distinct row_number() over ('+@SortString+') as RowNum,
  IMAGEID, SCANDATE, COUNT FROM #TABLE )AS RowConstrainedResult     
                    Where RowNum >'+cast(@FromRecord as varchar)+' AND RowNum <= '+cast (@ToRecord as varchar)+'
                     DROP TABLE #TABLE '
     exec (@Query)  
            PRINT @Query    

 SET NOCOUNT OFF  
END
```

This is my SP result

```
RowNum  IMAGEID         SCANDATE                COUNT
1   10000131    2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 1
2   10002626    2012-08-03 00:00:00.000 1
3   10003348    2012-09-06 00:00:00.000 1
4   10003589    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
5   10003590    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
6   10003591    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
7   10003592    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
8   10003595    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
9   10003596    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
10  10003598    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
11  10003599    2012-09-15 00:00:00.000 8
12  10004808    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
13  10004809    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
14  10004810    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
15  10004811    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
16  10004812    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
17  10004813    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
18  10004814    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
19  10004815    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
20  10004816    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
21  10004817    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
22  10004818    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
23  10004819    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
24  10004820    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
25  10004823    2012-09-20 00:00:00.000 14
26  10006686    2012-09-21 00:00:00.000 3
27  10006687    2012-09-21 00:00:00.000 3
28  10006689    2012-09-21 00:00:00.000 3
29  10006806    2012-09-27 00:00:00.000 1
30  10006816    2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 1
31  10006840    2012-10-02 00:00:00.000 1
32  10006877    2012-10-03 00:00:00.000 1
33  10006923    2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 3
34  10006936    2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 3
35  10006937    2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 3
36  10620408    2013-03-11 00:00:00.000 1
37  10622755    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
38  10622756    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
39  10622761    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
40  10622765    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
41  10622771    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
42  10622772    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
43  10622773    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
44  10622774    2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 8
45  10622891    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
46  10622892    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
47  10622893    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
48  10622895    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
49  10622896    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
50  10622897    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
51  10622898    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
52  10622899    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
53  10622900    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
54  10622901    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
55  10622902    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
56  10622903    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
57  10622904    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
58  10622905    2013-07-02 00:00:00.000 14
59  10622931    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
60  10622932    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
61  10622933    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
62  10622946    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
63  10622950    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
64  10622951    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
65  10622952    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
66  10622953    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
67  10622954    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
68  10622956    2013-07-03 00:00:00.000 10
69  10622979    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000 5
70  10622980    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000 5
71  10622981    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000 5
72  10623017    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000 5
73  10623018    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000 5
74  10623026    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
75  10623027    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
76  10623028    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
77  10623029    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
78  10623030    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
79  10623031    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
80  10623032    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
81  10623033    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
82  10623034    2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 9
83  10623059    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
84  10623060    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
85  10623061    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
86  10623062    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
87  10623063    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
88  10623064    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
89  10623065    2013-07-08 00:00:00.000 7
90  10623107    2013-07-09 00:00:00.000 1
91  10623112    2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 5
92  10623113    2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 5
93  10623122    2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 5
94  10623123    2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 5
95  10623124    2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 5
96  10623142    2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 2
97  10623143    2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 2
98  10623172    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
99  10623173    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
100 10623174    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
101 10623175    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
102 10623176    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
103 10623177    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
104 10623178    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
105 10623179    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
106 10623180    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
107 10623181    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
108 10623182    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
109 10623183    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
110 10623184    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
111 10623185    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
112 10623186    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
113 10623187    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
114 10623188    2013-07-15 00:00:00.000 17
115 10623195    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
116 10623196    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
117 10623199    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
118 10623200    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
119 10623203    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
120 10623204    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
121 10623206    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
122 10623207    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
123 10623212    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
124 10623213    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
125 10623214    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
126 10623215    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
127 10623216    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
128 10623217    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
129 10623218    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
130 10623223    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
131 10623225    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
132 10623227    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
133 10623228    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
134 10623229    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
135 10623230    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
136 10623231    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
137 10623232    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
138 10623234    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
139 10623236    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
140 10623237    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
141 10623238    2013-07-16 00:00:00.000 27
142 10623240    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
143 10623241    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
144 10623242    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
145 10623244    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
146 10623247    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
147 10623248    2013-07-17 00:00:00.000 6
148 10623841    2013-09-11 00:00:00.000 2
149 10623848    2013-09-11 00:00:00.000 2
150 10623921    2013-09-20 00:00:00.000 2
151 10623923    2013-09-20 00:00:00.000 2
152 10624106    2013-10-09 00:00:00.000 3
153 10624108    2013-10-09 00:00:00.000 3
154 10624116    2013-10-09 00:00:00.000 3
155 10624521    2013-11-23 00:00:00.000 2
156 10624523    2013-11-23 00:00:00.000 2
157 10625218    2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 2
158 10625219    2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 2
159 10625220    2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 1
160 10625245    2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 5
161 10625247    2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 5
162 10625250    2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 5
163 10625251    2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 5
164 10625252    2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 5
165 10625266    2014-01-09 00:00:00.000 1
```

And I need something like this

```
11/27/2007 12:00:00 AM 1001527,1001528,1001529,1001530,1001531,1001532,1001533,1001534,1001535,1001536,1001537,1001538,1001539,1001540,1001541,1001542 16 
  11/20/2008 12:00:00 AM 1002501,1002502,1002503,1002504,1002505,1002506,1002507,1002508,1002509,1002510,1002511,1002512,1002513,1002514,1002515,1002516,1002517,1002518,1002519,1002520 20 
  7/5/2011 12:00:00 AM 1015237,1015238 2 
  7/6/2011 12:00:00 AM 1015248,1015249,1015259,1015260,1015286,1015287,1015288,1015289,1015290,1015291,1015292,1015293 12
```

First column has scandate on which Group By is done, Second has image ids having same scan date in single cell - comma seperated, and lastly count colimn with count of image ids in single cell

Comment: What did you try ? You already have similar solution.

Comment: I have tried by querying datatable using linq, but i need to get the result in the datatable itself rather than applying linq on datatable

Comment: I have mentioned the result which I expect from the SP, which currently I am achieving with LINQ. But that wont satisfy my code needs, So I need the result directly from SP itself in datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The querstion [comma delimited list as a single string, T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18235693/116271) provides an illustration of how you can get a comma-delimited list grouped by a particular field.

The following code-snippet shows how you could take your resultant dataset and pivot it as illustrated in question above.

```
select distinct t1.scantime,
STUFF(
     (SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10), t2.ImageId, 120)
      FROM yourtable t2
      where t1.scantime = t2.scantime
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS imageids
from yourtable t1
```

However, you will want to refactor your existing stored proc, so that you are not doing unnecessary intermediate queries to get to this result.